# jQuery Mobile showing incorrect URL

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, url, jquery-mobile

On a MVC3 project I'm working on whenever I do a redirect to action on the controller the URL that is shown in the browser is the original request.  Not the redirected one.  Has anyone seen this or know of a workaround for it?

So for example. I can click a link with a `href` that equals...

`http://www.test.com/account/LogOut`

Which on the controller will redirect to the homepage, but once I'm logged out and the homepage is shown...the url still shows `http://www.test.com/account/LogOut`

This is causing some quirky behavior with a couple of other things that I've got going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the attribute 'data-ajax="false"' in your logout link.

Comment: awesome! Thank you.  I had seen that when I was looking over jquery mobile, but didn't think that it might fix this issue (I was actually having an issue determining WHY this would be useful).  Thanks again.